# AWS Lambda function times out but works on local instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

I am writing an NodeJS app on AWS that does the following:

- reads XML from remote URL
- parses the data and store it as JSON on DynamoDB
- uploads 8 image to s3 bucket

The code is running fine on my local node instance. The whole process usually takes less than 3 seconds to complete. I can confirm that by checking the AWS s3 bucket and DynamoDB.

However, when I packaged it to be run by Lambda, the operation expired even if the timeout was set to 5 minutes and maxed out the memory. When inspecting the log, I noticed the promise from the axios never returned when running on Lambda. Could someone spot any problem with my code? Thank you.

FYI, I am new to Lambda development. The way I deploy my code to Lambda is by adding the enclosing export.handler method to my local code, and zipping it up with the modules and package.json. I can certainly use some guidance on streamlining this process. I mention this because I am unsure if this has something to do with the problem.

Thank you.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
async function main() {
    await getData();
    updateDB();
    updateAssets();
}

let dataStore = {};

let s3Assets = [
    'photo1',
    'photo2',
    'photo3',
    'photo4',
    'photo5',
    'logoLarge',
    'logoSmall',
    'logoCompany'
];
let s3Status = {};

s3Assets.map( (i) => {
    // Initialize the status of all assets with 0 (false)
    s3Status[i] = 0;
})

let s3Ready = () => {
    let count = 0;
    s3Assets.map( (i) => {
        count += s3Status[i];    
    })
    console.log(s3Status);
    console.log(`Upload Count: ${count}`);
    if (count === s3Assets.length) {
        console.log(`[SUCCESS] All assets are updated`);
        console.log('< END: updateAssets');
    }
}

let getData = () => {
    ... // code omitted
}

let handleAsset = (asset) => {
    let src = dataStore[asset];
    let destination = dataStore.prefix + asset + '.jpg';

    axios({
        method:'get',
        url: src,
        responseType:'stream'
    }).then( (response) => {
        let body = response.data.pipe(zlib.createGzip());
        let fileType = 'multipart/form-data';

        let s3Promise = s3.upload({
            Bucket: 'someBucket',
            Key: destination,
            Body: body,
            ContentType: fileType,
            ContentEncoding: 'gzip'
        }).promise();

        s3Promise.then( (data) => {
            s3Status[asset] = 1;
            console.log('\n');
            console.log(`[SUCCESS] s3 Upload: ${data.Location}`);
        }).then( () => {
            s3Ready();
        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(`[ERROR] s3 Upload: ${error}`);
        });
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(`[ERROR] axios: ${error}`);
    });
}

let updateAssets = () => {
    console.log('> START: updateAssets');
    s3Assets.map( (i) => {
        handleAsset(i)
    });
}

let updateDB = () => {
    ... // code omitted
}

main();
```

}

Comment: I added the timeout option into axios request config inside my handleAssets function. As expected, axios is timing out.

Comment: Mixing promise chains and async/await makes things a bit hard to debug. I recommend refactoring the promise chain to use async/await and try/catch. But the main issue I see is you are never indicating success or failure; you never make a call to `callback` or return a response object

Comment: How have you configured the Lambda function? Is it configured to connect to a VPC & Subnet? Can you test whether it has Internet connectivity (eg try to retrieve a web page from somewhere)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you. I am not using VPC. The function is able to update the DynamoDB so I believe the problem has something to do with part that deals with the S3 upload.

Comment: @bwest. Thanks. I will add return values to my promise chain for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

1. My guess, since you said this program runs fine locally, is that you have incorrectly configured the [security group associated with the Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html). Make sure you have all outbound ports and correct inbound ports are open. To confirm this is the issue, or at least get more targeted feedback, try adding more detailed logging to you `axios` request. Here's a pretty verbose example from [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)...

```
}).catch( (error) => {
    console.log(`[ERROR] axios: ${error}`);
    if (error.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        console.log('error.response.data'error.response.data);
        console.log('error.response.status',error.response.status);
        console.log('error.response.headers',error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
        // http.ClientRequest in node.js
        console.log('Error request:',error.request);
    } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.log('Error message', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
});
```

You should receive an error on the `error.request` object that can help you troubleshoot further.

2. Much less likely the cause of your issue, but worth mentioning is the `.then()` methods you're chaining to `s3Promise` will execute asynchronously, so `s3Status[asset] = 1` won't necessarily complete before `s3Ready();` reaches the conditional `if (count === s3Assets.length)`  so you could have a race condition here. This is pretty unlikely, but I'd correct anyways because it could introduce a bug in the future. Run this example to see what I mean...

```
var test = ()=>new Promise(resolve=> resolve());

test()
  .then(()=> { setTimeout(()=>{console.log('one')},3000)})
  .then(()=>{console.log('two')})
```

This assignment `s3Status[asset] = 1` is synchronous so you should try moving your `s3Ready()` into that same `.then()` block...

```
s3Promise.then( (data) => {
    s3Status[asset] = 1;
    console.log('\n');
    console.log(`[SUCCESS] s3 Upload: ${data.Location}`);
    s3Ready();
}).catch( (error) => {
    console.log(`[ERROR] s3 Upload: ${error}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I made changes detailed in your two steps. The cloudwatch log shows multiple lines of the **Error request: Writable** error. I suspect this is due to the lambda role does not have enough privilege to write to the s3 bucket. However, it has the AmazonS3FullAccess policy assigned to it.

Comment: However, the s3 buckets often show their status as **Error** on the s3 list page, which I find quite unusual.

Comment: I added the error as an answer. It wouldn't let me post the error in reply because it's over the character limit. Thanks.